# Android PNG image not visible when overlaid on another image

Tags: android, png, imageview, overlay

I'm trying to overlay 2 ImageViews, one with the background and one with an animated (using AnimationDrawable). The animated frames are transparent PNGs.

The problem is that when both images visible, the overlaid animation does not show. If I add a JPG as one of the frames, only when that frames comes in line it is displayed so my presumption is there is something wrong with transparent images.

If I display only the animation without background image it show good.

This is part of the code:

```
    AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
    setContentView(layout);

    ImageView splash = new ImageView(this);
    splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.splashscreen);
    ImageView imageAnim = new ImageView(this);      
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    imageAnim.post(new Starter());
    imageAnim.setImageDrawable(animation);

    layout.addView(splash, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams(Global.Width, Global.Height, 0, 0));
    layout.addView(imageAnim, new AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams((int) (89 * Global.scaleX), (int) (68 * Global.scaleY), (int) (550 * Global.scaleX), (int) (413 * Global.scaleY)));
    imageAnim.bringToFront();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the background of your AbsoluteLayout instead of using a ImageView for the background?

Thus instead of the code:

```
AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
setContentView(layout);

ImageView splash = new ImageView(this);
splash.setImageResource(R.drawable.splashscreen);
```

use this:

```
 AbsoluteLayout layout = new AbsoluteLayout(this);
 layout.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.splashscreen);
 setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FrameLayout instead of AbsoluteLayout? Seems like it would solve your problem.

Comment: The thing is I;m composing an animated splash screen with one background image filling the whole screen and in some parts there are several animations running at fixed positions.

Comment: Still, AbsoluteLayout is deprecated and typically you can position everything where you want with a FrameLayout. Plus it would overlay your images just fine.